# Opencv crashes when initAsync is called

Tags: java, opencv, android-studio, android

I am using a simple code to open up a camera on opencv the app works fine on LG G Pro but crashes on samsung galaxy S4

Please Note that this activity is called via another activity through intent.

GameActivity.java

```
    public class GameActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewListener2 {
public static  final String MY_TAG = "MY_CUSTOM_MESSAGE";
private JavaCameraView javaCameraView;


private BaseLoaderCallback baseLoaderCallback= new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
    @Override
    public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
       switch (status){
           case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS:
           {
               Log.i(MY_TAG, "OPENCV Loaded");
               javaCameraView.enableView();
               break;
           }
           default:
               super.onManagerConnected(status);
       }
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    Log.i(MY_TAG, "onCreate Act 2");

    javaCameraView=(JavaCameraView)findViewById(R.id.MyJavaCam);
    javaCameraView.setVisibility(SurfaceView.VISIBLE);
    javaCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(this);


}




@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.i(MY_TAG, "onResume Act 2");
    OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_2_4_11, this, baseLoaderCallback);
    Log.i(MY_TAG, "onResume Act 2 done resuming");
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Log.i(MY_TAG, "onPause Act 2");

}

@Override
public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height) {

}

@Override
public void onCameraViewStopped() {

}

@Override
public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
    return  inputFrame.rgba();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if(javaCameraView != null)
    {
        javaCameraView.disableView();
    }
}
```

}

content_game.xml

```
<org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:id="@+id/MyJavaCam"
    opencv:show_fps="true"
    opencv:camera_id="any"
    />
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".GameActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_game"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.roundcube.gamewithserver.GameActivity" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
</application>
```

Logcat

> 07-10 04:13:48.107 11233-11233/com.roundcube.gamewithserver E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                 Process: com.roundcube.gamewithserver, PID: 11233
>                                                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.roundcube.gamewithserver/com.roundcube.gamewithserver.GameActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service Intent must be explicit: Intent { act=org.opencv.engine.BIND }
>                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3403)
>                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3434)
>                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2772)
>                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
>                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1449)
>                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
>                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5951)
>                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
>                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
>                                                                                  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service Intent must be explicit: Intent { act=org.opencv.engine.BIND }
>                                                                                     at android.app.ContextImpl.validateServiceIntent(ContextImpl.java:2052)
>                                                                                     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:2160)
>                                                                                     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:2138)
>                                                                                     at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:559)
>                                                                                     at org.opencv.android.AsyncServiceHelper.initOpenCV(AsyncServiceHelper.java:24)
>                                                                                     at org.opencv.android.OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.java:89)
>                                                                                     at com.roundcube.gamewithserver.GameActivity.onResume(GameActivity.java:85)
>                                                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1255)
>                                                                                     at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6412)
>                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3392)
>                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3434) 
>                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2772) 
>                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177) 
>                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1449) 
>                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
>                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5951) 
>                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400) 
>                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)

On using Logs i figured out that problem in this function call
`OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_2_4_11, this, baseLoaderCallback);

Please help me find a solution to this thank you.

Comment: may be you didn't give the uses-permissions in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Lack of permissions would have resulted in crash on other android devices as well , but it works fine except few android devices,just checked i have given uses-permissions.